# Tab Names Included in Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a problem on my website using JavaScript tabs where the tab names are included in the scrollbar, rather than just the content of the tabs, and so when the user scrolls down, the tab names disappear. I've put the code I have on JSFiddle linked below. If it's relevant, I'm embedding this in my site's main page by using:

```
<iframe class='demo' src='tabs.html' style='height:350px; width:700px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/08ghjmnv/

Can someone please show me how to change my code so that the tab names/headers are not included in the scrollbar, so they're always visible for the user to click to change tabs?

Thanks in advance :) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.tabs {
  position: fixed;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/08ghjmnv/2/)

Comment: Thanks Srinivas - that almost works, and the tab names/headers are visible with this, but they are still part of the scrolling section, and so they simply are displayed over whatever text is underneath them! Ideally I want them to be separated from the scrolling section.

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't work still unfortunately - same issue as before. The tab names are still part of the scrolling section and appear in front of the text when the user scrolls down.

Comment: I think the problem with what you linked is that it is putting a 60-pixel whitespace block at the top of the text, which is fine, but when the text scrolls, this whitespace goes off the top, rather than the 60-pixel whitespace block being constantly in place. Also I'm not sure this is the best way because it doesn't look great having a blank bit at the top of the text. Is there a way somehow to split the tab names from the actual text inside the tabs?